# AWS OpsWorks - Show Chef task output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, asset-pipeline, aws-opsworks

In the chef log, I've identified a task that takes a long time, and trying to figure out how to view it's output.

```
[2014-06-06T19:21:55+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[rake assets:precompile] action run (/srv/www/app/releases/20140606192141/deploy/before_migrate.rb line 11)
```

I've found the chef log file on the server and can see the normal chef output using the following:

```
tail -f /var/lib/aws/opsworks/chef/2014-06-06-19-21-20-01.log
```

It hangs on the previously mentioned log output until the precompile task is complete.

I know that the rake `assets:precompile` tasks normally gives output, but how do I view it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run it with --trace when you are incorporating that in your deploy code. This is what I use, but take care to modify the user/group/cwd values to what you need

```
execute "rake assets:precompile" do
  cwd release_path
  user deploy_user
  group deploy_group
  command "bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace "
  environment deploy_resource.environment
end
```